# List one column horizontally in table

Tags: sql, pivot

Apologies for the poorly worded question, I am not really sure how to phrase this.

I would like to take a comma delimited string and create a temp table (see following).

test_01,test_02,test_03,test_04,test_05,test_06,test_07,test_08
test_09,test_10,test_11,test_12,test_13,test_14,test_15,test_16
test_17,test_18,test_19,test_20,test_21,test_22,test_23,test_24
test_25,test_26,test_27,test_28,test_29,test_30,test_31,test_32
test_33,test_34,test_35,test_36,test_37,test_38,test_39,test_40

[image: tables]

I have tried.

1. I created temp table and comma delimited list in t-SQL
2. I can pivot the data but only get one column not entered into the table as expected.

Answer (score 0):

String_Split is what you're looking for.

```
SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT('test_01,test_02,test_03,test_04,test_05,test_06,test_07,test_08', ',')
```

returns

```
VALUE
test_01
test_02
test_03
test_04
test_05
test_06
test_07
test_08
```

You could pivot after the split if needed.

Comment: Thank You also trying to understand how to pivot the list into my desired format?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I arrived at solution.

```
    SELECT * FROM #te
UNPIVOT ([Value] FOR Cols IN ([Name])) Unp
PIVOT   (MAX([Value]) FOR Id IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10])) Piv
```

Adding custom row & id's

```
case when row_number() over (order by row) % 10 = 0 then 10 else row_number() over (order by row) % 10 end ID,
1 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT case when row_number() over (order by row) % 10 = 0 then 10 else row_number() over (order by row) % 10 end)) - 1) / 10 Row2
```